# How to insert into bigQuery partition table using nodeJS library

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have tried to specify partition decoration in form of [TABLE_ID]$YYYYMMDD when calling table.get() :

```
var table = dataSet.table(tableId + '$' + partition);
return table.get({autoCreate: false})
```

Also I have tried specifying the configuration.load.destinationTable.tableId in same way , and it did not work. 
any one have a clue on how to load to the specific partition with the nodejs biqQuery lib ?

Comment: Are you actually putting brackets around the table name? If you remove them does it work?

Comment: no brackets, that just a common place holder writing.

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question , I found there is no need to call table.get() since I only want to use createWriteStream to load the data. I specify the partition decoration in tableId for dataset.table(tableId) and for the createWriteStream I supply the options with destinationTable.tableId with the partition decoration.